# How to escape <br> in PHP nl2br function?

Tags: php

I would like to display `<br>` string by using `nl2br` function. I tried the following but `<br>` still won't appear in web browser.

```
<?php
echo nl2br("Hello <br> World");
echo nl2br("Hello \<br> World");
echo nl2br("Hello \<br\> World");
?>
```

Output in web browser

```
Hello
WorldHello \
WorldHello \ World
```

Desired output in web browser by using `nl2br()` function

```
Hello <br> World
```

Comment: Not sure what you think that [nl2br()](https://php.net/nl2br) does. The name means "new line to br". Neither the name nor what it does seem related to the use case you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't related to the `nl2br` function.  You're simply outputting HTML to the page so it's being interpreted as HTML.  To use characters which are otherwise meaningful to HTML, such as `<` and `>`, you can use their corresponding [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity):

```
echo nl2br("Hello &lt;br&gt; World");
```

(Note that `nl2br` isn't even needed here, since there are no newline characters in the given text.)

If the text you're working with isn't hard-coded like it is in the question but rather something from another data source, you can use [the `htmlentities` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to perform the same replacement of HTML "special characters":

```
echo htmlentities(nl2br($yourVariable));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
<?php
echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
?
```

> 

would output

```
foo isn't<br />
 bar
```

From the docs : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php